# What is a reason to speak of "open" before defining openness in a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, soft-question, metric-spaces

Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space. To define what it means for a subset of $E$ to be open in $E$, it is standard to first introduce sets of the form $\{ x \in E \mid d(y,x) < \delta \}$ where $y \in E$ and $\delta > 0$, calling it an "open" ball, or something alike, centered at $y$ of radius $\delta$. Then one proceeds to define the real sense of openness by saying that a subset $A$ of $E$ is called open in $E$ if and only if for every $y \in A$ there is some "open" ball centered at $y$ that is included in $A$. And then one proves that every "open" ball in $E$ is indeed open in $E$.

With respect to this logical order, it is tempting to say that the adjective "open" preceding "ball" is something meaningless until one proves that an "open" ball is really open.

So what is a reason to use the word "open" before defining the concept of openness in a metric space?

Comment: One defines an "_open ball_", rather than an "open" ball. At first it's just a terminology, but a posteriori the "open balls" will be open sets.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. But that is a language trick, just like removing discontinuity if possible. I think the "misuse" of  the word "open" may not be just like that! @SilviaGhinassi

Comment: But that is really the reason for using the word open before defining it. Because we are defining "open ball" and not yet "open set" (balls are a particular kind of sets in a metric space).

Comment: You consider the collection of "open balls" as the basis of the topology. You are not cheating by calling them open since any basis element belongs to the topology generated.

Comment: I am not taking the use of words to the rigid sense. I know that the "open" here may just be viewed as "dx" in an integral, which does not have meaning in itself until it is defined. I would like to know if it is just like that! @Giovanni

Comment: Do not focus so much on semantics. This kind of thought won't lead to any greater understanding.

Comment: @PVAL: Thank you for reminder. :)

Comment: @PVAL: Your reminder may open up a new question (soft). How can one tell or self-check if he understands mathematics more as a lawyer or more as an artist? Do you have a quick answer?

Comment: @GudsonChou My comment is mainly to say that thinking about the connotation (mathematical or otherwise) of the words in a phrase like "open ball" or "holomorphically convex function" is not as useful as thinking about the actual mathematical definition itself and examples of such. The words you call things don't affect the things very much.

Comment: @PVAL: Okay, if this is the case, then I am not "sinning".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this as an *incremental definition*, meaning that the "open ball" (and not "open" ball as eloquently mentioned) is defined first in a more *primitive* way of "openness" and then more complex open sets are defined with respect to more primitive "open" sets.

The primitive "open ball" is easier and more direct to define, than complex sets and a general concept of "openness"

**Note on comment** one can use a variation and not use the word "open" for open balls, and use another one, e.g "non-delimited balls" and then at the end, show the equivalence of "non-delimited balls" to "open" balls. 
But this becomes pedantic after a while.

Comment: Thank you. Do you agree my comment on the last line above? I think it lies in the same line of thought.

Comment: According to this answwer no. BUT one can use a variation and not use the word "open" for open balls, and use another one, e.g "non-delimited balls" and then at the end, show the equivalence of "non-delimited balls" to "open" balls. But this becomes pedantic after a while

Answer (score 7):

But long before you study metric spaces you learn in 7th grade to speak of open intervals and closed intervals and half-open intervals, etc.  And quite likely the only reason for using the term "open" for open sets in topology is that it generalizes the definition of the more special concept that you learned in childhood.

Here's the problem: one learns concrete instances of an idea first and more general forms later.  To escape that is impossible and probably undesirable.